# lock keys and release keys based on a button press using PySimpleGUI and pyhook

Tags: python, pysimplegui, pyhook

I have created a program where the user get access to the system keys such as ctrl and alt only with exiting a program with a button press. However when i run the program it does get stuck in the UI and wont allow me to do anything. Where am i wrong in this? Thanks in advance.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyWinhook
import pythoncom

layout=[[sg.Button('Exit')]]
        
def blockKeys(event):
    if event.Key.lower() in ['lwin', 'tab', 'lmenu']:
        return False    # block these keys
    else:
        # return True to pass the event to other handlers
        return True

def releaseKeys(event):
    return True
        
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, no_titlebar=True, location=(0,0), size=(800,600), keep_on_top=True).Finalize()
window.Maximize()
hm = pyWinhook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = releaseKeys
hm.KeyAll = blockKeys
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()

while True:
    event,values = window.read()
    print(event,values)
    
    if event =='Exit':
        hm = pyWinhook.HookManager()
        hm.MouseAll = releaseKeys
        hm.KeyAll = releaseKeys
        hm.HookMouse()
        hm.HookKeyboard()
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
        break;

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pythoncom.PumpMessages()` just sits idle and waits for Windows events. It means it will keep waiting there and do nothing. You use while loop in `PySimpleGUI`, so it is not necessary.

code revised as following,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyWinhook
import pythoncom

layout=[[sg.Button('Exit')]]

def blockKeys(event):
    if event.Key.lower() in ['lwin', 'tab', 'lmenu']:
        return False    # block these keys
    else:
        # return True to pass the event to other handlers
        return True

def releaseKeys(event):
    return True

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, return_keyboard_events=True , finalize=True)
hm = pyWinhook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = releaseKeys
hm.KeyAll = blockKeys
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
# pythoncom.PumpMessages()

while True:
    event,values = window.read()
    print(event,values)

    if event =='Exit':
        hm = pyWinhook.HookManager()
        hm.MouseAll = releaseKeys
        hm.KeyAll = releaseKeys
        hm.HookMouse()
        hm.HookKeyboard()
        # pythoncom.PumpMessages()
        break;

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much . This is exactly what i want